# Web Application JMeter load test for 1500 users in JMeter. App is responding slow

Tags: load-testing

We are doing load test for 1500 users using JMeter on web application. We are doing it batch wise. First batch 100 users and ramp up period 300 seconds and we put in loop for 15 times. Is this method correct for load testing?

Application is responding too slow at the time of load testing? Give me valuable suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

1500 threads != 1500 users.

Real user don't hammer application non-stop. Real user:

- needs to "think" between operations
- need to wait for response

So for instance:

1. You have 1500 users of your application
2. Each user makes a request each 15 seconds
3. Response time is 5 seconds

It means that each user hits server 3 times per minute. 1500 users will generate 4500 hits per minute which is 75 requests per second.

Above numbers are for reference only, you should modify them according to your scenario, SLA, etc. but my expectation is that you're generating ~20x more load than anticipated.

See [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) and especially pay attention to [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer), I believe it will help you to design your load test pattern.

In regards to "slowness" - it may be due to several factors (as well as combinations)

- Server is overloaded (not enough CPU, RAM, Network bandwidth, etc.). Use [PerfMon](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) plugin to monitor your server health during load test. If it is the case - hardware upgrade may be required
- Application (or web) server or database server are not configured properly. Default configuration parameters are "developer" oriented and not suitable for production.
- Your application source code is poorly designed and/or implemented. Use [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) tool to identify the bottleneck and contact the responsible developer in order to fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449575/need-an-urgent-help-regarding-jmeter
Kindly please review the above URL for complete detail and give me your valuable suggestion.